# XSLT iterating over child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This seems simple enough but I can't seem to get it to work.

My xml looks like this:

```
<bsar:BSAForm>
    <bsar:SubjectInformation>
        <bsar:LastNameOrNameOfEntity> Obama</bsar:LastNameOrNameOfEntity>
        <bsar:AddressBlock>
            <ucc:Address> 9 Dale Rd</ucc:Address>
            <ucc:City> Woodbury</ucc:City>
        </bsar:AddressBlock>
        <bsar:AddressBlock>
            <ucc:Address> 123 Fake St</ucc:Address>
            <ucc:City> Springfield</ucc:City>
        </bsar:AddressBlock>
    </bsar:SubjectInformation>
</bsar:BSAForm>
```

I need to iterate over both of these  elements and display the content.  My XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match=/bsar:BSAForm">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="bsar:SubjectInformation"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bsar:SubjectInformation">
    <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">4A</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">00001</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="bsar:LastNameOrNameOfEntity"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/> <!-- new line -->

    <xsl:apply-templates select="bsar:AddressBlock"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bsar:AddressBlock">

    <xsl:variable name="Addr" select="../bsar:AddressBlock"/>

    <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">4B</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">00001</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$Addr/ucc:Address"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$Addr/ucc:City"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/> <!-- new line -->
</xsl:template>
```

The output should be as follows:

```
4A 00001 Obama
4B 9 Dale Rd Woodbury
4B 123 Fake St Springfield
```

But instead, the output is coming out like this:

```
4A 00001 Obama
4B 9 Dale Rd Woodbury
4B 9 Dale Rd Woodbury
```

I have tried many different ways to do this, using a for each, using a for each like this:

```
 <xsl:variable name="header" select="."/>
 <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::bsar:TelephoneBlock[ancestor::bsar:SubjectInformation[1] = $header]">
```

or even passing in a counter from a for-loop and using that to access the specified element like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="bsar:TelephoneBlock">
    <xsl:variable name="Index">
        <xsl:number count="bsar:TelephoneBlock" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:call-template name="SubjectPhone">
        <xsl:with-param name="$Index"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template name="SubjectPhone">
    <xsl:param name="Index"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Telephone" select="../bsar:TelephoneBlock[$Index]"/>
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

In all these cases, it's displaying the first address twice.  Pleae let me know if you notice anything I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="Addr" select="../bsar:AddressBlock"/>
```

inside the `bsar:AddressBlock` template will set the `Addr` variable to a node set containing *all* the `bsar:AddressBlock` elements under the current element's parent, i.e. the current AddressBlock and all its sibling AddressBlock elements as well.  When you later come to

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Addr/ucc:Address"/>
```

this will select a node set containing all the `ucc:Address` child elements of all the AddressBlock elements in `$Addr`, then convert the *first* such element in document order to its string value (the definition of "string value" of a node set in XPath 1.0 is the string value of its first node).  This will always be the `ucc:Address` in the first AddressBlock, which is why you see the same address twice.

But the variable is un-necessary since you're in a template that applies to one AddressBlock at a time - just say

```
<xsl:template match="bsar:AddressBlock">
    <xsl:text>4B</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>00001</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="ucc:Address"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="ucc:City"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/> <!-- new line -->
</xsl:template>
```

the `select` expressions will be relative to the current AddressBlock and will extract its Address and City specifically, and produce

```
4A00001 Obama
4B00001 9 Dale Rd Woodbury
4B00001 123 Fake St Springfield
```

This does rely on the fact that there's a leading space at the start of each Address and City value in the original XML, you may prefer to say something like

```
<xsl:template match="bsar:AddressBlock">
    <xsl:text>4B </xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>00001 </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ucc:Address)"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ucc:City)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/> <!-- new line -->
</xsl:template>
```

(note that `xml:space="preserve"` is the default for `<xsl:text>` so you don't need to specify it explicitly)

Comment: Right you are.  May you live to be a thousand years old.